# Slide div from bottom on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to obtain [this](http://www.jamieoliver.com/healthy-living-tips/) effect (you need to scroll down a bit to see the divs sliding in)

I'm not that good with JS but I managed to make the divs fade in from 0 opacity to full opacity using this code:

```
  tiles = $(".recipe").fadeTo(0, 0);
  $(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
      tiles.each(function(i) {
          a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
          b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
          if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
      });
  });
```

Can anyone help me optain the desired effect? I need the divs to slide up from 0 opacity to 100 percent opaque, from bottom to top, when scrolling.

Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a possible solution:

```
var scrollCb = function () {
    var tiles = $(".tile:not(.animated)");
    var $window = $(window);
    var b = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();

    tiles.each(function (i) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var a = $this.offset().top + $this.height();

        if (a < b) {
            $this.addClass("animated").addClass("fadeInUp");
        }
    });
};

$(scrollCb);

$(window).scroll(scrollCb);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74u765q2/4/

[animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) realizes the animation part.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it. this works flawlessly. I also didn't know about animate.css to be honest

Answer (score 0):

That page uses a jquery library called waypoints.
You have to download the waypoint library, this library has a lot of functions for scroll event:

for example:

> ```
> $('#example-offset-percent').waypoint(function() {
>     notify('25% from the top');
> }, { offset: '25%' });
> ```

this code triggers the notify when the object is 25% from the top of the screen.

here is the link to the page:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/